# Personal pronoun after displaying ideas

Tags: word-usage

Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez tweeted:

> US Representative,NY-14 (BX & Queens). In a modern, moral, & wealthy society, no American should be too poor to live. [100]% **People-Funded, no lobbyist  [money bag emoji]. She/her.**

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/AOC)

"She/her" appears to refer back to the author herself in this self-introduction.  If so, it looks a bit odd to me after introducing your ideas to mention your gender.  I am not sure whether this feeling of mine can be justified based on the grammar.

Does "She/her" appears natural to you there?

Comment: It is what people do these days although I would have expected her to put it in her profile not in the tweet

Comment: The gender thing is all over the place now. In e-mails, in letters and online. People state what their gender preferences are. And even around here, for some people.

Comment: @mdewey, if you click through you will see that it is the profile, not an actual tweet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ocasio-Cortez did *not* "tweet" the text you quoted—it was not a specific "message" or "status." Rather it is her *profile*, a little blurb that describes the owner of the account in general.

In recent years people have become more cognizant of the role that personal pronouns play in peoples' lives, particularly the fact that people who are transgender or otherwise not "conventionally" gendered may be referred to by pronouns that they feel do not align with their gender. This can be uncomfortable to them, so some people advertise their preferred pronouns in various places, like their Twitter profiles. Some cisgender people do this as well, both to eliminate any possible confusion and to normalize the practice so people who use non-obvious pronouns do not feel abnormal for sharing that information.

Regardless of the reason, it makes perfect sense for that information to be included in a Twitter profile alongside other identifying information or deeply-held beliefs that the user wishes to share on a more ongoing basis than just a single tweet.